# Batch %errorlevel% returns 0 in FOR loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I am trying to make a loop that will go through a set of text files in specified directory searching for a string. The result is reported based on whether the string is found. But the `%errorlevel%` always returns 0 and evaluates to 0.

```
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion

    FOR %%G IN (*.txt) DO (
        find /i "My text string" "%%G"
        ECHO %date% %time% :  errorlevel is %errorlevel% >> %report_dir%\%computername%.txt
        IF %errorlevel% EQU 1 (
            ECHO %date% %time% : String found >> %report_dir%\%computername%.txt

            GOTO:copy_log
        )

    )

    ENDLOCAL
```

Raymond did you mean that?:

```
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion

    FOR %%G IN (*.txt) DO (
        find /i "My text string" "%%G"
        IF %errorlevel% (
            ECHO %date% %time% : String found >> %report_dir%\%computername%.txt

            GOTO:copy_log
        )

    )

    ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: As noted in the documentation, you use exclamation points for delayed expansion and percent signs for immediate expansion. You're still using `%ERRORLEVEL%`, which will be expanded immediate. You want it delayed, so you need `!ERRORLEVEL!`. Or you can just avoid the entire problem by saying `IF ERRORLEVEL 1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer to make `For` loops call branches.  It prevents variable expansion problems:

```
For %%G In (*.txt) Do Call :ScanFile "%%G"
Exit /B

:ScanFile
Find /i "My text string" "%~1"
If %ErrorLevel%==1 (
    Echo %date% %time% : String found >> %report_dir%\%computername%.txt
    Goto :CopyLog
)
Exit /B

:CopyLog
...
Exit /B
```

Comment: This is the most easy solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

`%ERRORLEVEL%` is being expanded too soon. You can just avoid the problem entirely by using:

```
IF ERRORLEVEL 1
```

---

Or for further details, see this explanation of "delayed environment variable expansion" from the `SET /?` help text:

> Finally, support for delayed environment variable expansion has been
>   added.  This support is always disabled by default, but may be
>   enabled/disabled via the `/V` command line switch to CMD.EXE.  See `CMD /?`
>
> Delayed environment variable expansion is useful for getting around
>   the limitations of the current expansion which happens when a line of
>   text is read, not when it is executed.  The following example
>   demonstrates the problem with immediate variable expansion:
>
> ```
>     set VAR=before
>     if "%VAR%" == "before" (
>         set VAR=after
>         if "%VAR%" == "after" @echo If you see this, it worked
>     )
> ```
>
> would never display the message, since the `%VAR%` in BOTH IF statements
>   is substituted when the first IF statement is read, since it logically
>   includes the body of the IF, which is a compound statement.  So the IF
>   inside the compound statement is really comparing "before" with
>   "after" which will never be equal.  Similarly, the following example
>   will not work as expected:
>
> ```
>     set LIST=
>     for %i in (*) do set LIST=%LIST% %i
>     echo %LIST%
> ```
>
> in that it will NOT build up a list of files in the current directory,
>   but instead will just set the LIST variable to the last file found.
>   Again, this is because the %LIST% is expanded just once when the FOR
>   statement is read, and at that time the LIST variable is empty. So the
>   actual FOR loop we are executing is:
>
> ```
>     for %i in (*) do set LIST= %i
> ```
>
> which just keeps setting LIST to the last file found.
>
> Delayed environment variable expansion allows you to use a different
>   character (the exclamation mark) to expand environment variables at
>   execution time.  If delayed variable expansion is enabled, the above
>   examples could be written as follows to work as intended:
>
> ```
>     set VAR=before
>     if "%VAR%" == "before" (
>         set VAR=after
>         if "!VAR!" == "after" @echo If you see this, it worked
>     )
> ```
>
> Again, this is because the %LIST% is expanded just once when the FOR
>   statement is read, and at that time the LIST variable is empty. So the
>   actual FOR loop we are executing is:
>
> ```
>     for %i in (*) do set LIST= %i
> ```
>
> which just keeps setting LIST to the last file found.
>
> Delayed environment variable expansion allows you to use a different
>   character (the exclamation mark) to expand environment variables at
>   execution time.  If delayed variable expansion is enabled, the above
>   examples could be written as follows to work as intended:
>
> ```
>     set VAR=before
>     if "%VAR%" == "before" (
>         set VAR=after
>         if "!VAR!" == "after" @echo If you see this, it worked
>     )
>
>     set LIST=
>     for %i in (*) do set LIST=!LIST! %i
>     echo %LIST%
> ```

Answer (score 2):

As Raymond says you're evaluating %ERRORLEVEL% for the echo, which will almost always ( never say never ) return 0.

Something along the lines of the following will do better:

```
FOR %%G IN (*.txt) DO (
    find /i "My text string" "%%G"
    SET error = %errorlevel% 
    ECHO %date% %time% :  errorlevel is %errorl% >> %report_dir%\%computername%.txt
    IF %error% EQU 1 (
        ECHO %date% %time% : String found >> %report_dir%\%computername%.txt
        GOTO:copy_log
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while looping through registry keys/values, and came to this post. My "reg query" always had ERRORLEVEL 0 in a for loop.

Here's my solution:

`for %%s in (%ToBeUninstalled%) do (
REG QUERY "%KEY64%\%%s" | find /i "UninstallString" > NUL && (msiexec.exe /x %%s /qb) || (echo Software not installed)
)`

KEY64 being HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall